# Spring Boot multiple context path aliases

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Following is the Spring Boot configuration for context path

```
server.servlet.context-path=/rootContext
```

Is it possible to create multiple aliases for the same so that same application is served on `/rootContext_2` and `rootContext_3`?

I essentially want to configure different security mechanisms for different aliases.

Comment: You could try [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).

Comment: Profiles would override each other, I need both the context paths to be active simultaneously

Comment: For now I have used `Netflix Zuul` route to create a proxy URL for the application.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to have multiple context paths for the same Spring Boot application. The context path is used to define the base URL of the application, and it can only be set once.

As mentioned in the comments, you could use something external like a reverse proxy to handle the URL mapping and apply different security mechanisms based on the URL pattern.

Comment: It's been long since I posted this, but it is possible. I didn't use external proxy but just added Zuul dependency to the project, which allowed me to add multiple context paths in it's proxy configurations

Comment: I understand that Zuul is now considered deprecated; coming to this question today, I'm attempting to use spring-cloud-gateway instead. [This page](https://medium.com/@m1326318/the-evolution-of-our-microservices-architecture-transitioning-from-zuul-to-spring-cloud-gateway-2d59ea702a12) might be a useful resource for anyone else who finds themselves in the same position.